# Update Column Value with the help of vue js in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

This is my blade of laravel

```
<!-- Main Container -->
<main id="main-container">
   <!-- Page Content -->
   <div class="content" id="app">
        <h2 class="content-heading">Accessory Details</h2>
        <div class="block block-themed">
            <div class="block-header block-header-default">
                <div class="block-options">
                    <a href="{{ route('accessory.create') }}"><button class="btn btn-success pull-right">New Request</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="block-content">
                <form action="" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-12" for="example-select2-multiple">Store Location</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-11">
                            <select class="form-control" name="store" style="width: 100%;" required>
                                <option value="">Choose Select Store location..</option>                                    
                                @foreach($stores as $store)
                                    <option @if($store_selected == $store->id) selected @endif value="{{ $store->id }}">{{ $store->channel_id }} | {{ $store->street_name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-alt-success">
                                Filter
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Dynamic Table Full -->
        <div class="block">
            <div class="block-content block-content-full">
                @include('errors.error')

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-full1" data-page-length='50'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">#</th>
                                <th class="text-center">User</th>
                                <th>Store</th>
                                <th class="">Request Date</th>
                                <th class="">Status</th>
                                <th class=""></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($accessories as $accessory)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $accessory->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $accessory->user->name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $accessory->store->channel_id }} - {{ $accessory->store->street_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $accessory->request_date }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $accessory->status }}</td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="getdetails({{ $accessory->id }})" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details">Details</button></td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Dynamic Table Full -->

        

        <b-modal id="modal-1" title="Details" v-model="dialog"  @ok="handleOk">
            <form ref="form" @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit">   
                @csrf
               {{-- <input type="hidden" v-model="id"/> --}}
                <select class="form-control" name="status">
                    <option>Pending</option>    
                    <option>Ordered</option>    
                    <option>Received</option>    
                </select>

                <br><br>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Vendor</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>QTY</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-for="line in lines">
                        <td>@{{line.name}}</td>
                        <td>@{{line.description}}</td>
                        <td>@{{line.qty}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            
        </b-modal>

    </div>
</main>

<script >
    window.app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        mounted: function() {
        },
        data() {
            return {
                dialog: false,
                lines: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            
            getdetails: function(id) {
                let self = this;
                this.lines = [];
                axios.get('/accessory/' + id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.dialog = true;
                    self.lines = response.data;
                    console.log(self.lines)
                    //$(location).attr('href', '/accessory')
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    alert('Error');
                });
            },
            handleOk(bvModalEvt) {
                // Prevent modal from closing
                bvModalEvt.preventDefault()
                // Trigger submit handler
                this.handleSubmit()
            },
            handleSubmit() {
                axios.post('/accessory/status-change/' )
                .then(response => {
                    $(location).attr('href', '/accessory')
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    alert('Error');
                }); 
            }
        },
        created() 
        {
            
        }
    })
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-dataTable-full1').DataTable( {
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
        } );
    });

</script>
```

Here for the following statement in model , i want to bind it with accessory_request_id which i am recieving {{--  --}}. So what should i select for v-model?

If i check for console.log(self.lines), it returns me an array with accessory_request_id.

Then later on with the help of accessory_reques_id, i want to update status in database.

So follow is my controller code --

```
   {
       //return 'test';
       //dd($request->all());
       $accessory_request = AccessoryRequest::findorfail($request->id);
       $accessory_request->status = $request->input('status');

       $accessory_request->save();
       return ['message' => 'Status Updated'];
   }


In web.php -- route is 
Route::post('accessory/status-change','AccessoryController@status_change');


please help me to resolve it
```